# Parse.com REST API Call gives invalid session token error

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I have logged into parse from cloud code using `Parse.User.logIn`

After a successful login have retrieved session token using user._session

```
Parse.User.logIn(request.params.userdata.email, "sdfisadufhkasdjhf", {
success: function(user) {
       response.success(user._sessionToken);
   },
error: function(user, error) {
   }
});
```

This session token is passed to the client which then makes a REST API call by setting the token in the header.

However, the rest API call is not successful and returns invalid session token error.

REST API call works perfect when I don't send session token for requests that don't need authentication

From chrome console, I can see that the headers are set correctly and the value of session token is same as `Parse.User.current().getSessionToken()`

in app.config()

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Parse-Application-Id'] = "dxfhgfxhxhxhxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdgerstrattgrft";

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Parse-REST-API-Key'] = "gfhjjhfjfjjchfjcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

From controller

$scope.createGroup = function()
        {

```
        shan = $scope.creategroup;
        $http.post('https://api.parse.com/1/functions/addGroup',   $scope.creategroup, 
        { headers: {
          'X-Parse-Session-Token':sessionToken
        }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        alert("success : "+JSON.stringify(data));

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error : "+JSON.stringify(data));
      });


    }
```